# Which Controllers to implement

Tags: spring-mvc

I had to make an Application that displays a form to search data from parameters.

Search results would be displayed on the same page.

I am using Spring 3.0 Framework (XML Format) with Spring MVC and Hibernate with Annotations.

My Applications only select data from DB and displays data on to from.

**My Question** is which Controllers (MultiActionController, SimpleFormController,etc) should be used for this requirement?

Comment: This is too open-ended a question. You need to read the documentation on how to write Spring MVC (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleFormController` already `@Deprecated`. You can use `MultiActionController` instead.